# check if record exists (PDO)

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to check if a record exists in a database, but when I run the code below, all I get is the message confirming a database connection. I do not get either of the two messages after parsing the code. I am new to PDO and tried all kinds of ways to make this work but still get no result. Can anyone help please?

```
<?php
$telephone= ($_GET [ 'telephone' ]);
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=gosdirect", $username, $password);
    /*** echo a message saying we have connected ***/
 echo 'Connected to database<br />';

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM directory WHERE telephone == $telephone";
if ($res = $dbh->query($sql)) {

    /* Check the number of rows that match the SELECT statement */
  if ($res->fetchColumn() > 0) {

           echo 'The telephone number: ' . $telephone. ' is already in the database<br />';
         }
     /* No rows matched -- do something else */
  else {
      echo 'No rows matched the query.';
    }
}

$res = null;
$dbh = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
   {
  echo $e->getMessage();
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few things. MySQL does not use the `==` equality operator, instead you should just use `=`. In addition, since you're using PDO, it might be better to set up Prepared Statements.

Finally, since you use `COUNT(*)`, your query will always return 1 record. You need to update your code as follows:

```
$sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS `total` FROM directory WHERE telephone = :phone");
$sql->execute(array(':phone' => $telephone));
$result = $sql->fetchObject();

if ($result->total > 0) 
{
    echo 'The telephone number: ' . $telephone. ' is already in the database<br />';
}
else 
{
      echo 'No rows matched the query.';
}
```

It's probably worth noting too that since you're receiving `$telephone` direct from the `$_GET` super-global, you shouldn't really output it unsanitized to the browser (for reasons of XSS vulnerabilities). I'd recommend updating your first `echo` statement as follows:

```
echo 'The telephone number: ' . strip_tags($telephone). ' is already in the database<br />';
```

Comment: Thank you so much @BenM. That works perfectly. It was staring me in the face but I couldn't see it - lol

Answer (score 1):

No need of == in

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM directory WHERE telephone == $telephone";
```

It should be

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM directory WHERE telephone = $telephone";
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you, but the result is just the same. I trfied the single = in the begining and trying == was one of the alternatives that made no difference.  Many thanks

Comment: I am disappointed that someone seems to think my question showed no research effort and marked it as a minus. I have been trying to do this for two days and have researched many answers in many forums, as well as poring over chapters in different books, but still to no avail.

Comment: It is better to mention your efforts in the question. So that people can help you without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that (without SQL-Injection ;)):

```
$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM directory WHERE telephone = :phone';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindParam(':phone', $_GET['telephone'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$stmt->execute();

if($stmt->fetchColumn()) die('found');
```