# PHP how to check if record exist (PDO)

Tags: php, pdo

i try to do insert when record is not exist with the following

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM people WHERE first_name = :first_name");
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$count = $statement->fetchColumn();
if ($count === 1)
{
    echo "First name Exist";
}
else
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO people (first_name, last_name) VALUES (:first_name, :last_name)";
    for($count = 0; $count<count($_POST['hidden_first_name']); $count++)
    {
    $data = array(
    ':first_name' => $_POST['hidden_first_name'][$count],
    ':last_name' => $_POST['hidden_last_name'][$count]
    );
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute($data);
    }  
}
```

it still inserting to database that makes duplicate first name. and also try accepted answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26863879/check-if-record-exists-pdo) but i can't make it work.

Comment: try `if ($count == 1)`

Comment: `:first_name` wasn't bound in the first query; you're relying on it to work only in the second; that won't work.

Comment: You might like to make this first search a little more specific! How many people do you know called Dany?

Answer (score 1):

At first, you didn't provide appropriate value for your `:first_name` token

```
// Let's say value to match = $_POST['first_name']

$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM people WHERE first_name = :first_name");
$statement = $db->prepare($query);

// Specify value to match in the `execute` call
$statement->execute(array(':first_name' => $_POST['first_name']));

//Now try this to confirm if the result is fetched

if ($statement->fetch())
{
    echo "First name Exist";
}

//else it doesn't exist fetch!
else
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO people (first_name, last_name) VALUES (:first_name, :last_name)";
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    for($count = 0; $count<count($_POST['hidden_first_name']); $count++)
    {
    $data = array(
    ':first_name' => $_POST['hidden_first_name'][$count],
    ':last_name' => $_POST['hidden_last_name'][$count]
    );
    $statement->execute($data);
    }  
}
```